# How to traverse <Item> node in <TravellerInfo> without considering "<Item>" node which is child node of it.

Tags: java, xml-parsing

How to traverse  node in  without considering "" node which is child node of it.

With bellow example code i am getting 9 loops. But i should get 3 loops.

NodeList TravellerInfo=BookingresponseEle.getElementsByTagName("TravellerInfo");

Element TravellerInfoEle=(Element)TravellerInfo.item(0);

NodeList Items=TravellerInfoEle.getElementsByTagName("Item");

XMl  is below

```
<TravellerInfo>        
<Item>          
    <TicketNumber>5899553184513</TicketNumber>          
    <PaxType>ADT</PaxType>          
    <Title> MR</Title>          
    <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>          
    <LastName>TEST</LastName>          
    <DateOfBirth />          
    <SegmentInformation>            
    <Item>             
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184513</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2777</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>BLR</Origin>              
        <Destination>VTZ</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 06:50</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 08:55</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>            
    <Item>              
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184513</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2704</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>VTZ</Origin>              
        <Destination>MAA</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 19:15</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 21:00</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>  
    </SegmentInformation>        
 </Item>
 <Item>          
    <TicketNumber>5899553184512</TicketNumber>          
    <PaxType>CHD</PaxType>          
    <Title> MSTR</Title>          
    <FirstName>TESTC</FirstName>          
    <LastName>TESTC</LastName>          
    <DateOfBirth>15/07/2009</DateOfBirth>          
    <SegmentInformation>            
    <Item>              
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184512</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2777</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>BLR</Origin>              
        <Destination>VTZ</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 06:50</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 08:55</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>            
    <Item>              
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184512</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2704</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>VTZ</Origin>              
        <Destination>MAA</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 19:15</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 21:00</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>            
    </SegmentInformation>        
    </Item>
          <Item>          
    <TicketNumber>5899553184514</TicketNumber>          
    <PaxType>ADT</PaxType>          
    <Title> MR</Title>          
    <FirstName>TESTT</FirstName>          
    <LastName>TESTT</LastName>          
    <DateOfBirth />          
    <SegmentInformation>            
    <Item>             
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184514</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2777</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>BLR</Origin>              
        <Destination>VTZ</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 06:50</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 08:55</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>            
    <Item>              
        <AirlinePNR>MWVGUH</AirlinePNR>              
        <TicketNo>5899553184514</TicketNo>              
        <FlightNumber>2704</FlightNumber>              
        <Origin>VTZ</Origin>              
        <Destination>MAA</Destination>              
        <DepartureDateTime>24/07/2012 19:15</DepartureDateTime>              
        <ArrivalDateTime>24/07/2012 21:00</ArrivalDateTime>              
        <AirCraftType>AT7</AirCraftType>              
        <CarrierCode>9W</CarrierCode>              
        <ClassCode>W</ClassCode>              
        <FareBasis>W2SA14JK</FareBasis>              
        <FrequentFlyerNumber />              
        <SpRequest />              
        <MealsPreference>VGML meals status : UN</MealsPreference>            
    </Item>            
    </SegmentInformation>        
</Item>      
  </TravellerInfo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at [getChildNodes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29). That will get you the immediate descendants of the node you call it on.

You should then check each node in the resultant `NodeList` to determine it's an `<Item>` (you'll most likely get the text nodes inbetween elements etc. so checking is essential - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690544/12960) and its question for more info)