# Android DOM Parser, how to get child nodes?

Tags: android, xml, dom

I have following XML structure

```
<urlset><!--  lib.meine_sitemap [begin] -->
    <menu level="1">
         <title>Products</title>
         <url>index.php?id=395</url>
         <menu level="2">
              <title>Title</title>
              <url>index.php?id=426</url>
              <menu level="3">
                  <title>Title</title>         
                  <url>index.php?id=437</url>
                  <cat>41</cat>
                  <cat>42</cat>
              </menu>
              <menu level="3">
                  <title>Title</title>                        
                  <url>index.php?id=436</url>
                  <cat>80</cat>
              </menu> 
         </menu> 
    </menu>
(...)
</urlset>
```

Now I want to get all child nodes of "menu level 1". To display the title in a list view. When I am using:

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("menu");
```

I get ALL Elements and not only the child nodes of menu level 1.

When I am using

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getChildElements();
```

This seems to work, but then I cant do this again:

```
nodes.item(0).getChildElements();
```

How can I achieve that I only get the child menus of a node?

Thanks!

Comment: Propably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689900/get-xml-only-immediate-children-elements-by-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got a solution. The trick ist to use `node.getNextSibling()`

The following code gets all `menu` Tags and then read the `title` Tag of them and add it to an Arraylist.

```
private void diveDeep(int index)
{
    currentNode = (Node)currentNodes.get(index);

    currentNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Node childNode = currentNode.getFirstChild();

    while(childNode.getNextSibling() != null)
    {
        childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();
        if(childNode.getNodeName().equals("menu"))
        {
            currentNodes.add(childNode);
            NodeList nodes = childNode.getChildNodes();

            for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
            {
                if(nodes.item(i).getNodeName().equals("title"))
                {
                    valueList.add(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```